# How to set constraint of imageView and title label inside a UIButton with autolayout

Tags: image, uibutton, autolayout, constraints, title

I have a problem using autolayout with uibutton. What I want is make a button's image and its title 10 points gap, and image is on the right,while title is on the left.What should I do to achieve that? Appreciate for any suggestion!

Comment: You can set edge inset for button image and title in attribute inspector.

Comment: question is the button's width and height are not fixed, they are changed decided by button's super view,which would turn it to a mess